# The formula for a function of output prices

Tags: prestashop, product, discount

This function displays the price in the front.

```
{$product.price_amount}">{$product.price}
```

How do I add a formula to this function that will allow me to output the result with a discount?

For example, the amount currently displayed is 1000 $

It is necessary that the amount is displayed with the deduction of a **discount of 7%** of this price.

And displayed 930 $

Answer (score 0):

On a template level, it's not the best way to define the calculation logic for price.

Rather create catalog price rules from Prestashop Admin.

http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS17/Catalog+Price+Rules